# Div not removed by click jquery?

Tags: jquery

This [link1](http://jsfiddle.net/AzW7a/1/) - work

```
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test2"></div>
$('.test2').click(function(){
$('.test2').remove();
```

This [link2](http://jsfiddle.net/AzW7a/) - dont work

```
<div class="test">test</div>
$('.test').click(function(){
$('body').prepend('<div class="test2"></div>');
});
$('.test2').click(function(){
$('.test2').remove();
});
```

why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).on('click','.test2',function(){
    $('.test2').remove();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/AzW7a/2/)

Comment: @Ap313 please refer the documetation [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use event delegation since it's created on the fly

```
$(document).on("click",".test2",function(){
    $(this).remove(); //you can use 'this' instead
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Write:

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    $('body').prepend('<div class="test2"></div>');
    $('.test2').click(function(){
        $('.test2').remove();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AzW7a/3/)

OR

```
$('.test').click(function () {
    $('body').prepend('<div class="test2"></div>');
});
$(document).on('click','.test2',function () {
    $('.test2').remove();
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AzW7a/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Using the live click, it is working fine. Refer the fiddle update

http://jsfiddle.net/AzW7a/11/

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    $('body').prepend('<div class="test2"></div>');
});
$('.test2').live('click',function(){
    $('.test2').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click','.test2',function(){
    $('.test2').remove();
});
```

*Reason:Why the above code works and yours does not?*

1.You are dynamically adding elements.In simpler words,the element you appended did not exist when DOM was loaded.

2.You need to assign [Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) for any future addition of elements.The method that we usually use like  `.click(...) , .on(..)` etc only applies to the elements that are currently in the DOM.

3.This is how you provide Event Delegation.

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.class', function(){.........})
```